# Search box constantly opening up

Tags: visual-studio-code, dialog, box, wakatime

The "pop up" dialog box is essentially preventing me from using the VS code editor, as the constant "prompting" means that I can't type anything in the editor.
[popup dialog image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUZtn.png)

The image summarizes my challenge.
Somehow whilst adjusting the setting for Tailwind CSS (VS Code environment) I somehow managed to mess up the VS code settings, and I can't work out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try reinstalling your code environment.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback , and advice followed.However due to me have a "senior" moment the actual problem was actually embedded in the response box.Essentially I needed to enter an API update(apparent) for a time tracking system that I use - "Wakatime"